# Customizing close opportunity dialogue box in crm 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I need to add a new field to the close opportunity dialog box.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Form is not covered by the SDK and therefore not customizable. You could try to edit the .aspx-file, which is totally unsupported, but you are not able to change the built-in process of this dialog.

See the list of [Unsupported changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928224.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your reply. can you please tell me which .aspx file i need to modify.

Comment: Take a look at 'SFA\opps\dlg_closeopp.aspx'